# how to set TextField in 4 columns spaces JavaFx

Tags: javafx, textfield, gridpane

I want to make a *calculator* in *JavaFx*. I am using *GridPane* in order to set the position of calculator buttons and a Textfield. My question is: how can I set TextField in 4 column spaces?

In the following example:

```
  TextField userTextField = new TextField();
    grid.add(userTextField, 0, 0,3,3);
```

What does it mean the coordinates 0,0, 3, 3 in grid? What does it stand for?
Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

In the following javafx program i only want to set TextField and buttons of my calculator sample :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class calculadora_css extends Application{

     @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
               primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Welcome");
               GridPane grid = new GridPane();
               grid.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
               grid.setHgap(20);
               grid.setVgap(20);
               grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

               TextField userTextField = new TextField();

               grid.add(userTextField, 0, 0,3,1);

               Button btn1 = new Button("7");
               grid.add(btn1, 0,1);
               Button btn2 = new Button("8");
               grid.add(btn2, 1,1);
               Button btn3 = new Button("9");
               grid.add(btn3, 2,1);
               Button btn3_3 = new Button("+");
               grid.add(btn3_3, 3,1);
                Button btn4 = new Button("4");
               grid.add(btn4, 0,2);
               Button btn5 = new Button("5");
               grid.add(btn5, 1,2);
               Button btn6 = new Button("6");
               grid.add(btn6, 2,2);
               Button btn6_6 = new Button("*");
               grid.add(btn6_6, 3,2);
                Button btn7 = new Button("1");
               grid.add(btn7, 0,3);
               Button btn8 = new Button("2");
               grid.add(btn8, 1,3);
               Button btn9 = new Button("3");
               grid.add(btn9, 2,3);
                Button btn9_9 = new Button("-");
               grid.add(btn9_9, 3,3);
                Button btn10 = new Button("0");
               grid.add(btn10, 0,4);
               Button btn11 = new Button(".");
               grid.add(btn11, 1,4);
               Button btn12 = new Button("=");
               grid.add(btn12, 2,4);
               Button btn12_12 = new Button("/");
               grid.add(btn12_12, 3,4);

            Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 275);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);

            scene.getStylesheets().add
           (calculadora_css.class.getResource("calculadora_css.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.show();

    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```

i want to set the buttons below the TextField but in the final compiled program the +, *,-,  / buttons are pushed to the right, i tried to arrange the buttons according to the commentaries above, thank you very much, anyhelp is appreciated

Comment: Maybe you have a look here, it explains all about GridPanes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY118

Comment: Or just read the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html)

Answer (score 0):

The extra parameters apart from `columnIndex` and `rowIndex` that you find are the `columnspan` and `rowspan` respectively.

ColumnSpan allows you to use more than one column for a control that has been added as a child to the GridPane. Similarly, RowSpan allows you to use more than one row.

Either, you can use the [`setColumnSpan(Node child,Integer value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setColumnSpan-javafx.scene.Node-java.lang.Integer-) to set the colspan or you can also do it using the [`add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, int colspan, int rowspan)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-int-int-) for defining the columnspan while adding a child.

So, coming to your question,

> grid.add(userTextField, 0, 0,3,3);

stands for adding the `userTextField` control to :

- columnIndex 0 of the gridPane
- rowIndex 0 of the gridPane
- colSpan 3 to use 3 columns starting from column index 0
- rowSpan 3 to use 3 rows starting from row index 0

Comment: In the following javafx program i only want to set TextField and buttons of my calculator sample :